# Is 'In-Memory' the default configuration of the objectstore module in Mule?

Tags: mule

I thought that the default configuration of the objectstore module in Mule was In-Memory (http://mulesoft.github.io/mule-module-objectstore/mule/objectstore-config.html#config)

I have an objectstore configured as such in my app:

```
<objectstore:config name="sourceConfigStore" entryTtl="60000" ></objectstore:config>
```

I reference the store from a java component like so:

```
    ObjectStoreModule objectStore = (ObjectStoreModule) eventContext.getMuleContext().getRegistry().lookupObject("sourceConfigStore");

    objectStore.store((String)sourceConfig.get("url"), sourceConfig, true);
```

This works for the most part, except I discovered today that this was writing files to disk when I got the following error:

```
Message               : Unable to create a canonical file for parent: C:\git-ucd\.mule\.mule\edus-esb-rss-aggregator\objectstore and child: DEFAULT_PARTITION\news.ucdavis.edu/xml/getnews.php?type=category&categories=General+Interest&format=rss.obj (org.mule.api.MuleRuntimeException)
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. Invalid argument (java.io.IOException)
  java.io.WinNTFileSystem:-2 (null)
2. Unable to create a canonical file for parent: C:\git-ucd\.mule\.mule\edus-esb-rss-aggregator\objectstore and child: DEFAULT_PARTITION\news.ucdavis.edu/xml/getnews.php?type=category&categories=General+Interest&format=rss.obj (org.mule.api.MuleRuntimeException)
  org.mule.util.FileUtils:402 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MuleRuntimeException.html)
3. Unable to create a canonical file for parent: C:\git-ucd\.mule\.mule\edus-esb-rss-aggregator\objectstore and child: DEFAULT_PARTITION\news.ucdavis.edu/xml/getnews.php?type=category&categories=General+Interest&format=rss.obj (org.mule.api.MuleRuntimeException) (org.mule.api.store.ObjectStoreException)
  org.mule.util.store.PartitionedPersistentObjectStore:278 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/store/ObjectStoreException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
java.io.IOException: Invalid argument
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize0(Native Method)
    at java.io.Win32FileSystem.canonicalize(Win32FileSystem.java:414)
    at java.io.File.getCanonicalPath(File.java:618)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
```

So, my question is whether or not the default behavior of the objectstore module is in fact to use an in-memory store.  If that is the case, I guess my next question would be 'how did I override that default behavior with my above config and code'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default implementation is in memory. 
Then again if you're running your application from Mule studio that's not the case as in MuleStudio by default it persists things to a file. This is why on your run configuration in the general tab you have the option to delete these files in each run.

In any case the easiest way to force the in memory will be something like this:

```
<objectstore:all-keys config-ref="_defaultInMemoryObjectStore"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Dds.  Since I was using java to retrieve items from the store, the above message processor xml wouldn't work.  I changed my config to the following, though, which solved the problem of forcing the store to be 'in-memory' only.   <objectstore:config name="sourceConfigStore" entryTtl="60000" partition="SourceConfigStore" persistent="false" ></objectstore:config>